# I want to draw arc with color filled with animated gradient

Tags: java, android, animation, kotlin, gradient

I'm drawing multiple arcs on canvas in a circular way, It's like speedometer(but not speedometer) , arc color changed with gradient color when speed reaches to high or low or average, But I want that, gradient color should be changed with animation, like if arc is in black color, when speed becomes high, arc should be changed to red gradient with smooth gradient animation.

I have wasted my lots of time.
please help me to solve it out.

Thanks in advance.

This is `onDraw()` method code:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val unitMinTempValue = Utils.getUnitCircleDegreeFromThermos(minTempValue.toFloat()).toFloat()
    val unitMaxTempValue = Utils.getUnitCircleDegreeFromThermos(maxTempValue.toFloat()).toFloat()
    val unitMinFixTempValue = Utils.getUnitCircleDegreeFromThermos(Const.minFixTemp.toFloat()).toFloat()
    val unitMaxFixTempValue = Utils.getUnitCircleDegreeFromThermos(Const.maxFixTemp.toFloat()).toFloat()

    matrixGradient = Matrix()
    matrixGradient?.postRotate(15f)

    canvas.drawArc(mRect!!, unitMinFixTempValue - 2.5f, unitMaxFixTempValue - unitMinFixTempValue + 4.5f, false, mPaintDefault!!)

    if (isEnable) {

        when (mode) {
            Const.mode_heat_cool -> {
                canvas.drawArc(mRect!!, unitMinTempValue - 2.5f, unitMaxTempValue - unitMinTempValue + 4.5f, false, mPaintBlack!!)

                when (currentTempValue) {
                    in 43..(minTempValue - 1) -> {
                        positions = floatArrayOf(unitMinFixTempValue / 390, unitMinTempValue / 390)
                        setGradientPosition(Const.orange, positions)
                        canvas.drawArc(mRect!!, unitMinFixTempValue - 2.5f, unitMinTempValue - unitMinFixTempValue + 4.5f, false, mPaintOrange!!)
                    }
                    in minTempValue..(maxTempValue) -> {

                        canvas.drawArc(mRect!!, unitMinTempValue - 2.5f, unitMaxTempValue - unitMinTempValue + 4.5f, false, mPaintBlack!!)
                    }
                    in maxTempValue..97 -> {

                        positions = floatArrayOf(unitMaxTempValue / 390f, 1f)
                        setGradientPosition(Const.blue,position) canvas.drawArc(mRect!!, unitMaxTempValue - 2.5f, unitMaxFixTempValue - unitMaxTempValue + 4.5f, false, mPaintBlue!!)
                    }
                }

            }


        }
    }
}

private fun getRect(): RectF {

    centerX = measuredWidth / 2
    centerY = measuredHeight / 2
    radius = Math.min(centerX, centerY)

    val startTop = STROKE_WIDTH / 2

    val endBottom = 2 * radius - startTop

    return RectF(startTop.toFloat(), startTop.toFloat(), endBottom.toFloat(), endBottom.toFloat())

}

private fun setGradientPosition(type: String, positions: FloatArray) {

    if (type == "blue") {
        colorsBlue?.let {
            val gradientBlue = SweepGradient(measuredWidth.toFloat() / 2, measuredHeight.toFloat() / 2, it, positions)
            gradientBlue.setLocalMatrix(matrixGradient)
            mPaintBlue?.shader = gradientBlue
        }


    } else {
        colorsOrange?.let {
            val gradientOrange = SweepGradient(measuredWidth.toFloat() / 2, measuredHeight.toFloat() / 2, it, positions)
            gradientOrange.setLocalMatrix(matrixGradient)
            mPaintOrange?.shader = gradientOrange

        }

    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

when red pin moved, draw arc with different angle with different color

Comment: On Android? Have an example of what you want to achieve? Otherwise it's just a wish list. *"I have wasted my lots of time"* - Then maybe you should provide some more insight into what you have "tried", so we don't waste more of it

Comment: Yes, In android, I have applied gradient color to an arc. All I want is arc color should be changed with animation in when OnDraw method of view is called 

Please see for animation ,`https://freakycoder.com/android-notes-55-animated-gradient-background-instagram-app-login-screen-d8d8c363000a`
 but i dont know how to implement this animation when we draw arc.

Comment: You need to use _Path_ and make calculation as per speed becomes high or low if you'r using custom view with canvas.

Comment: If possible then share your code!

Comment: @Piyush I have added my code now, can you please check it.

Comment: Do you want to something like [this](https://github.com/vitorhugods/AvatarView), [this](https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/circular-progress-bar) or [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/758)?

Comment: @Piyush please check attached images

Comment: So does it work proper? Do you just need animation?

Comment: Yes,working fine .. I just want animation. I have used the Swip gradient, the color should be changed smoothly like the link I have sent above from gray to blue gradient or gray to orange gradient @Piyush

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @Piyush not yet, please help me if you can!